# Doctrine keeps updating DATETIME on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, doctrine

I have parent entity class:

```
namespace App\Model\Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class ParentEntity
{
    /**
     * @var int|null
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;    

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", columnDefinition="DATETIME on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
     */
    protected $modifiedOn;
}
```

and everytime I run `php bin/console o:s:u --dump-sql` or `--force` the console prints out that X queries will be executed and every query is for `modified_on` column.

```
 ALTER TABLE contact CHANGE modified_on modified_on DATETIME on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
 ALTER TABLE about_us CHANGE modified_on modified_on DATETIME on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
 ALTER TABLE image CHANGE modified_on modified_on DATETIME on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
 ...
```

In MySQL database everything is setup correctly:

```
CREATE TABLE `about_us` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`modified_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

---

So my question is why is this happening? Did I miss some configuration/annotation for Doctrine? Or do you have to specify this attribute in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably after [Lifecycle Callbacks](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html). if so this is the way to go:

```
namespace App\Model\Entities;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
abstract class ParentEntity
{
    /**
     * @var int|null
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;    

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $modifiedOn;

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function setModifiedOn()
    {
        $this->modifiedOn = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Peyman Mohamadpour provides probably the more php-standard way of doing this, however I want to address the original question - why is this happening.

And I can see 2 reasons right out of the box...

### The core problem - `columnDefinition`

columnDefinition allows you to define non-portable - therefore non-doctrine - things and since doctrine will not generate it when trying to generate state of the current table schema it sees it as a change, and [the documentation is pretty clear about that](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/reference/basic-mapping.html#property-mapping):

> `columnDefinition`: Allows to define a custom DDL snippet that is used to create the column. Warning: This normally **confuses the SchemaTool to always detect the column as changed.**

#### Secondary issue

Your entity column definition is not the same as definition in DB - in database your column is NULLable,

in the doctrine entity **`ORM\Column` has `nullable = false`** by default

(be aware that **`ORM\JoinColumn` is not the same - it's `nullable = true`** by default!)

... so doctrine detects it's not null automatically => detects change => wants to update => but that would be fixed after first schema update... well fixed... the schema would match ... for your case the proper fix for this part would be to explictly define `nullable=true` and also make the property nullable with the null as default value - as this is an old Q I will intentionally show the modern attribute approach:

```
    use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    ...
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_IMMUTABLE, nullable: true]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $modifiedOn = null;

    #[ORM\PreUpdate]
    public function setModifiedOn(): void
    {
        $this->modifiedOn = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }
```

You also may need to define `#[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks]` on the class, but I am not absolutely sure about that - it may heavily depend on the Doctrine version since I've seen some cases where it was not defined and it worked, but also where it was defined and is still in latest stable...

### Conclusion

- avoid <del>`columnDefinition`</del> whenever possible
- for these cases use [Lifecycle Callbacks](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks) (also [documented in Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-callbacks))
- use [`\DateTimeImmutable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) whenever possible and don't forget to tell the doctrine you're using that
- use `Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types` for defining doctrine-known types